# Run linq-to-XML operations without namespace

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a lot of code like this in one of my projects (from before I knew how to use yield return):

```
    public EditorialReviewDTO[] GetEditorialReviews(string URL) {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(URL);
        XNamespace ns = xml.Root.Name.NamespaceName;
        List<EditorialReviewDTO> result = new List<EditorialReviewDTO>();

        List<XElement> EdRevs = xml.Descendants(ns + "EditorialReview").ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < EdRevs.Count; i++) {
            XElement el = EdRevs[i];
            result.Add(new EditorialReviewDTO() { Source = XMLHelper.getValue(el, ns, "Source"), Content = Clean(XMLHelper.getValue(el, ns, "Content")) });
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }

    public static string getValue(XElement el, XNamespace ns, string name) {
        if (el == null) return String.Empty;

        el = el.Descendants(ns + name).FirstOrDefault();
        return (el == null) ? String.Empty : el.Value;
    }
```

My question is: is there a way to run these queries *without* having to pass around the namespace?  Is there a way to say `xml.Descendants("EditorialReview")` and have it work even if that element has a namespace attached?

Needless to say, I have no control over the XML format returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `Descendants("EditorialReview")` selects elements with local name `EditorialReview` in no namespace so that call does not select any elements which are in a namespace. However for your method `getValue` you could eliminate the `XNamespace` argument `ns` and instead use `public static string getValue(XElement el, XName name)` and then simply call it as e.g. `getValue(el, ns + "Source")`.